# Creating dynamic dropdowns in a multiple item form based on the previous row

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a network map stored in a database as pairs of connections between nodes.  Users create a path name (through a form) and then connect a route through the network from one node to another by creating node-path pairs in a table (this table also stores a routing order number that stores the order of the path through the network).

Currently, this is structured with a multi-item sub-form embedded in the main route form, allowing users to create route-node pairs, which are stored with a routing order number that stores the order of each node.

My problem is that the dropdown for the node selection in this path shows every node in the project, and I would like it to use the network connection map to only show the list of nodes that are one step away from the current node (determined by the highest integer in the routing order column for that route).

If I can figure out how to reference the previous row in the sub-form, I should be able to figure this out (use that previous row plus the network map as a filter on the list of nodes), but I can't find anything on the web on how to do that.

Comment: Could set a global variable or a TempVar or an UNBOUND textbox on form each time a record is edited.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand the question, but if you're looking for a way to find the row before the current row, I think this could be the answer.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "[ID]=" & Me.ID
rst.MovePrevious
MsgBox "ID: " & rst.Fields("ID")
```